# Concurrently read epub files on Android

Tags: android, epub

I have an epub file on HTTP server, When I try to read Ex: Author Name, Book Title etc it read the whole epub file. I want to read page by page instate of reading whole file.
NB: [here](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) the Android epublib reference.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL(bookPath);
            // create the new connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            // and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();
            // this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Load Book from inputStream
            book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(inputStream);
            maxLocation = book.getTableOfContents().size();
            // get the book's title
            String bookName = book.getTitle();
            String authorName = book.getMetadata().getAuthors().toString();

            Log.i("Books", "Title: " + bookName + " Author: " + authorName);
            title = "Title: " + bookName + " Author: " + authorName;

            int i = 1;
            for (TOCReference index : book.getTableOfContents()
                    .getTocReferences()) {
                stringBuffer.append(index.getTitle() + "</br>");
                i++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }
```

Comment: What is `EpubReader` in your code? From which library does it come from?

BTW, an EPUB file is a (ZIP) container of several files. You need to download it all, before inspecting its metadata.

Moreover, there is no notion of "page" in an EPUB.

Please clarify your question.

Comment: [here](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) the Android epublib reference.

Comment: Please ask me if I unable to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying that you are using epublib.

epublib assumes that you have your EPUB file locally, so you must download it (entirely!) before you can read its metadata.

If you are designing a client/server application, you might want to extract and store on the server side only the metadata, and access those from the client for searching/retrieval purposes. Then, when your user chooses the book she wants, you download to her device only that particular EPUB.